# Setting output path for Kotlin/JS distribution / webpack output

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-js

When building my project using the `browserDistribution` Gradle task, Kotlin/JS puts the output which has been processed by webpack into `/build/distributions/myProject.js`.

Instead, I would like my output to go into a folder called `/output` in my project's root directory.

How can I change the path where my distributions are put after running through webpack?

I'm using the Gradle Kotlin DSL if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The Kotlin/JS Gradle plugin provides a `distribution` API which can be used to adjust the output directory of a project. To put the final distribution output of a project into a folder called `output` in the project root, one can use the following snippet (it works in both Gradle Kotlin DSL and Groovy Gradle):

```kotlin
browser {
    distribution {
        directory = file("$projectDir/output/")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The output path can be set via the `outputPath` property in the `commonWebpackConfig` or the `destinationDirectory` property in the `webpackTask` block , e.g.:

```kts
// kotlin dsl
kotlin {
    js {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            // either configure here
            commonWebpackConfig {
                outputPath = file("$projectDir/build/distributions/assets/js")
            }

            // or here
            webpackTask {
                destinationDirectory = file("$projectDir/build/distributions/assets/js")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to set the output directory in order to include the build artifacts into another project, say a backend project running ktor that needs to serve the client build artifacts, then setting the output directory directly is the wrong approach.

In order to be safe to share between projects and allow maximum performance during the build (parallelism), such artifacts must be exposed via Gradle's "outgoing configurations" [mechanism](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html).

In the client (producer) project definition, declare a `browserDist` configuration like this:

```kotlin
val browserDist: Configuration by configurations.creating {
  isCanBeResolved = false
}
```

and in the same project declare that the output directory of the `jsBrowserDistribution` task should be inluded in the artifacts of this configuration:

```kotlin
artifacts {
  add(browserDist.name, tasks.named("jsBrowserDistribution").map { it.outputs.files.single() })
}
```

Then, in the backend (consumer) project definition, declare a `browserDist` configuration like this:

```kotlin
val browserDist: Configuration by configurations.creating {
  isCanBeConsumed = false
}
```

and specify the dependencies of this configuration (change `:client` to the name of the project containing the client build artifacts):

```kotlin
dependencies {
  ... other dependencies ...

  browserDist(project(":client", "browserDist"))
}
```

and then finally register a task to copy the artifacts and serve them up. For example, for a ktor server, we'll want to copy the artifacts into a `resources/web` directory so they can be served via `singlePageApplication`.

In the backend build, define:

```kotlin
tasks.register<Copy>("processWebResources") {
  from(browserDist)
  into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("resources/main/web"))
}

// make processResources depend on processWebResources
// it may be useful to gate this behind a property specified only
//  for production builds, otherwise this will run even in dev,
//  where we're probably using the client `jsRun` directly
tasks.named("processResources") {
  if (providers.gradleProperty("bundleProductionJs").isPresent) {
    dependsOn("processWebResources")
  }
}
```

In ktor, define a route like this:

```kotlin
singlePageApplication {
  useResources = true
  filesPath = "web"
}
```

Adjust as necessary for your specific backend.